# Howto find out if a harddisk is sleeping or spinning?

Tags: c, linux

My program frequently polls disks for changes but i don't want them to wake them up nor wait 10sec until they are accessible.

I know that on the command shell i can use `hdparm -C /dev/sda` to find out if a drive is in active/idle or standby mode. But hdparm does need root rights and is not installed by default so i can't use it in my program.

How can i do the same with a C function?

Comment: And if you know the answer for Windows or MacOS it would be nice to have them too in case i ever try to port my program.

Comment: Are you on an ssd or hdd or hybrid?  This only makes sense on an hdd.  On an ssd or hybrid, it may already be in a cache so it won't bother "spinning up".

Comment: Is what you need possibly watching a directory (or file) for changes, to know when writing is done? You might be interested in the `inotify` API.

Comment: I'm asking because I didn't understand your purpose. You're looking for a non-root way to get an HDD's power mode status (That doesn't depend on hdparm)? I took a very short look at hdparm and it looks like it's querying the HDD rather directly (sending ATA commands to get the state).

Comment: I don't need to explain the purpose. I know it's possible because gdisk can do it. It shows the "zzz" letters when the device is sleeping. So i thought i could get around reading the source code but it seems i have to and answer my own question once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hdparm uses a SCSI ioctl on `/dev/sda` to obtain the power mode. This usually requires root because regular users won't have read/write permissions on block devices.

If you have udisks2 installed and running you can get around this by invoking a [dbus method](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/gdbus-org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata.html#gdbus-method-org-freedesktop-UDisks2-Drive-Ata.PmGetState) on the system bus:

- Service: org.freedesktop.UDisks2
- Object Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/<ID of the hard drive>
- Method: org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata.PmGetState

udisks2 runs as root to obtain the necessary power state (standby/active/idle), but any application with access to the system bus can query udisks2.

Comment: I know gdisk don't need root rights to show me that information.
I'm sure there is a way to get it from "/sys/block/sda"  but what path to use. Also get thinks like if it is a HDD or SDD from there.

Comment: Is udisk2 mandatory part of every GNOME and KDE? In this case i would be allowed to use it.

Comment: When you says gdisk, do you mean "GNOME Disks", the GUI application? It uses this dbus API. I don't think gdisk the command line utility will run as non-root, it needs to open the block device. I think udisks2 would be part of most GNOME/KDE environment, although maybe it's possible to uninstall