# How to check the drive power state?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, dbus, hard-drive

I'm trying to read the drive power state (active/standby/sleep) using Python under Linux/Raspberry Pi.

I found [here this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65995054/2697895) and it says that I can do it using `udisks2 dbus`:

```
you can get around this by invoking a dbus method on the system bus:

Service: org.freedesktop.UDisks2
Object Path: /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/<ID of the hard drive>
Method: org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata.PmGetState
```

But I don't know how to implement it...

I managed to write this code that is executed without errors, but I don't know how to continue it... Can you help me ?

```
from pydbus import SystemBus

def get_drive_power_state(drive_path):
    bus = SystemBus()
    udisks = bus.get(".UDisks2")
    drive_obj = bus.get("org.freedesktop.UDisks2", drive_path)


    return None


drive_path = "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD20NMVW_11EDZS3_WD_WXV1EA57RT6E"
power_state = get_drive_power_state(drive_path)

print(f"Drive Power State: {power_state}")
```

Comment: Continue it?  What are you trying to do?  Do you get a proper {power_state} value?  If not what do you get?  You need to show debugging details, and explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't get a proper {power_state} value because the function is not finished. I want to execute the method `org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata.PmGetState` but I don't know how to get there. It returns the {power_state} value.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a method on a [DBus object](https://github.com/LEW21/pydbus/blob/master/doc/tutorial.rst#d-bus-objects), you would need to specify which DBus interface the method belongs to.
In this case, the `PmGetState` method belongs to the `org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata` interface, so that is the interface we specify in the method call.

```py
import dbus

def get_drive_power_state(drive_path):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    proxy = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks2", drive_path)
    iface = dbus.Interface(proxy, "org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Drive.Ata")
    
    power_state = iface.PmGetState({})
    
    return power_state

drive_path = "/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/WDC_WD20NMVW_11EDZS3_WD_WXV1EA57RT6E"
power_state = get_drive_power_state(drive_path)

print(f"Drive Power State: {power_state}")
```

Comment: I get this error:
 raise TypeError(self.__qualname__ + " got an unexpected keyword argument '{}'".format(kwarg))
TypeError: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get got an unexpected keyword argument 'dbus_interface'

Comment: @MarusGradinaru OK, I have updated the code to try another way to call that method.

Comment: `dbus` is another library ? 'Cause I don't have it... And if I try to install it, it says that it doesn't exists.

Comment: @MarusGradinaru It is [`dbus-python`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/), the Python bindings for D-Bus.

Comment: It seems that everything it's against me tonight :( I try to install it with `pip install dbus-python` and I get all kind of errors in red...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the most elegant way to do this, but if the driver supports it, you can get the power management status through the sysfs. For instance, read the file `/sys/class/nvme/nvme0/power/runtime_status`.

Comment: That reads "unsuported" to all my drives... :( It was too good to be true. I don't think there is a solution for this problem.